# Toast does not appear

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

I'm developing an Android app and I'm a little bit confused why my Toast is not shown in my app.

The toast is not located in an Activity. Therefore, this is my solution. In the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);

    // Init context
    InstanceHandler.setContextOfMainActivity(this);
}
```

In the class InstanceHandler:

```
private Activity mActivity;
public Context mContext;

public void setContextOfMainActivity(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
}
```

and in the affected class Connection.java (**NOT** extends Activity) I'm calling the toast:

```
public class Connection{

    public void test(){
        Toast.makeText(InstanceHandler.mContext, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. The app aborts the following code after the Toast.

Comment: Remove the InstanceHandler and try to use this Toast : `Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` or you can use also `getApplicationContext()` instead

Comment: Where do you call Toast.makeText(InstanceHandler.mContext, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); ?

Comment: Save a reference to the Context from your MainActivity inside BleConnector, so that you can use it for toasting

Comment: You need a context to show a toast. Pass a context via parameter.

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile - for example, you're accessing non-static members without an object. Please post the code you're actually using. A good solution is not to fix the `Context` access but to pass in a `Context` as a parameter where it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Just This Over There

```
Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Use That Class Like This

```
public class Connection{
    Context mContext;
    public Connection(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

         mContext = context;
    }

    public void test(){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also tell me from where you are calling this class. pass context with that

Comment: @Knossos It depends on Context. If you pass the Context of Foreground class to Background Class. It will surely work

Comment: @Knossos Definitely that is to be

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your are using Toast.makeText(..).. outside the InstanceHandler class .If your are using inside other Activity then use that activity directly and if you are using inside InstanceHandler class then use

mContext in place of InstanceHandler.mContext

hope this will helpful to you.